# Psutil 'Process' object has no attribute 'terminal'

Tags: python, psutil

Ok so I started using psutil 2.1.1 with Python 2.7.6 and I wanted to test some commands as follows:

```
import psutil
psutil.pids()
p = psutil.Process(6096)
p.name() # gives u'googletalk.exe'
p.terminal()
```

These are the commands I used from the psutil 2.1.1 documentation, I used every command from the process management section.

The moment I use p.terminal I get the error:

> 'Process' object has no attribute 'terminal'

I used the above code in both the shell and a new file with the same result.

Comment: It seems you forgot to ask the question.

Comment: Does `p.terminal()` return `None` or does it throw an Exception? What OS are you using? (The Windows implementation e.g. does not define this method)

Answer (score 1):

```
p = psutil.Process(6096)
p.name() # gives u'googletalk.exe'
```

According to the process name *googletalk.exe* you are using Windows. The `Process.terminal()` method is not implemented for Windows (Windows doesn't have the concept of Terminals in a way *nix-like systems have).

The common implementation of `class Process` (_ *init_*.py) refers to the platform-specific implementations ([line 610](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/psutil/__init__.py#610), assigned by [line 317](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/psutil/__init__.py#317)) - that's why you get an error (not defined in [_pswindows.py](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/psutil/_pswindows.py#220)).